# How to programmatically click google maps icons

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

Take a look at this map:

[image]

This map pops up when you visit https://www.hertzcarsales.com/, and click "Change" next to with "Within X miles of Y" dropdown selector. Anyway, I cannot right click on the little H's to inspect with FireBug, and I can't seem to figure out how to access the urls attached to each using [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir).

When I click on an H I can do

```
b.as(:text,/Visit this Store/).href
```

but I can't get them all though.

Comment: The modal triggers a request to: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?5m2&1d40.7447&2d-73.99130000000002&7sUS&9sen&key=AIzaSyDwfATIrUFRgm_y0YLTA6OGOxIVdYpaUXk&callback=_xdc_._opv003&token=48061

Comment: So it cannot be done then?

Comment: You can parse that content

Comment: Nevermind. I misread your question. You want to be able to retrieve that map URL from the first page and I assumed you just wanted to get its content.

Comment: Where is the rest of the watir code?  How did you get to the point where you could retrieve the hrefs for the links?  Did you have to deal with the iframe?

Comment: The `href` attribute is in a `div` tag (with a `class` attribute of `locationPhone`) that is dynamically created when the icon is clicked.  So you will have to click each icon to collect the `href` for each location.

Comment: @orde, yes, I'm aware of that, but those aren't available for parsing. I suspect I need to `.execute_script` something.

Comment: if you have no way to get a css selector on the icons it's going to hard. I think you should retitle this question to "how to programmatically click google maps icons", it's an interesting question, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, I don't think you can. If you peel the map down to where the pins are, they are contained in a `CANVAS` tag which Selenium cannot see inside.

I did find another way to get what you want. Go here instead, https://www.hertzcarsales.com/locations. Click on the blue "Find a Car Sales Location" button in the middle of the page. That will launch basically the same dialog except there are location summaries on the left side of the page. You can click the View All link in the top left. Now you have every location's info and you can grab the links you wanted.

Comment: Yup, I'm gonna have to agree with JeffC here -- that seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Damn... Well, I only spent $0.75 for someone to do this manually on Amazon Mechanical Turk. They produced 85 results.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the complete? list is at the bottom and I can do `browser.as(:text,/Used Cars/).href`.

Comment: Huh... Doing that I end up getting 94 results... My worker was off by 11... Or this second list is more complete...